# What are the salient features and differences between advaita, dvaita, and vishistadvaita philosophies?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism

I would like to know what are the key features of each philosophy. What are their similarities and differences.

Comment: The  answer will be too broad.  Need to limit the question. These philosophies are already separately discussed on this site. Take a look at similar posts already present  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12272/differences-between-advaita-vishishtadvaita

Comment: @SwiftPushkar you might mean [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14779/277) :)

Comment: @Pandya - Yes Exactly . i was sure about the existence of some  duplicate post , but haven't found it . Bravo ...

Comment: @Pandya Can you reopen this one and close it as a duplicate?